# onListItemClick not being invoked

Tags: android

I am following a online course and I can across this exercise that for some reason is not working. The onListItemClick() is not being invoked. I have tried troubleshooting this but I couldn't get rid of the issue
Please help me solve this issue.

My code for MainActivity.java is

```
package hk.ust.cse.comp107x.greetfriend;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends ListActivity{
String names[];

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    names=getResources().getStringArray(R.array.friends);
    //setListAdapter((ListAdapter)new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.friend_item,names));
    setListAdapter( new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.friend_item, names));
}

@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    Intent in=new Intent(this,ShowMessage.class);
    in.putExtra("message","Good Day "+names[(int) id]+"!!");
    startActivity(in);
}

}
```

Code for ShowMessage.java is

```
package hk.ust.cse.comp107x.greetfriend;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ShowMessage extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_show_message);
    Intent in=getIntent();
    String message=in.getStringExtra("message");
    TextView textMessage=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textMessage);
    textMessage.setText(message);
}
}
```

My code for friend.xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:text="Friend Name"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:autoText="true"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    android:padding="20dp"
    android:id="@+id/textview">

</TextView>
```

And finally my code for strings.xml is

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">GreetFriend</string>
    <string-array name="friends">
        <item>John</item>
        <item>Paul</item>
        <item>George</item>
        <item>Ringo</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

Comment: you haven't set click listener on your list

Comment: @VivekMishra 
I am sorry I don't fully understand. I am new to Android. Could you please walk me through it?

Comment: show your setListAdapter method

Comment: setListAdapter( new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.friend_item, names));                                                                                                                      This is the setListAdapter() method call. No method other than the ones showed above have been been explicitly defined.@VivekMishra

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following code for your Friend.xml and run the code...

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

      <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    >
         <TextView      android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:text="Friend Name"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    android:padding="20dp"
    android:id="@+id/textviewfriend">

</TextView>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I am sorry I don't fully understand. I am new to Android. Could you please walk me through it?

Comment: The layout is ok. The ListActivity class extends Activity class which uses the friend layout that I should you above.
The problem is the method onListItemClick() that is not being envoked.

Comment: remove the AutoText and try to run

Comment: and your setLstAdapter is wrong you should change this to  setListAdapter( new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.friend_item, R.id.textView , names));
}

Comment: Its working now. the problem was not in the adapter or anything else.
It was the autotext.
Thank a lot @Mr.Popular